# How much tire pressure with bigger tires?

Tags: tire-pressure

I have a 2015 grand Jeep Cherokee. It originally had Goodyear 17” with recommendation of 33psi. I upgraded to a nitto 20” and the tire says max 50 psi. How do I know how much air to put in?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of driving you plan on doing. If you're planning on just doing city driving, the recommended tire pressure is between 30 -35 psi. Please note, that your tire pressures will fluctuate slightly depending on the weather outside so you may need to top up again once the weather cools.